# got warning for connection to s3 that left open in unitest

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm using the following class for checking objects that exist in s3 :

```
class HistoryManagerS3():

    def __init__(self, bucket_name):
        client = boto3.Session(profile_name='my-custom-profile')
        self.s3 = client.resource('s3')
        self.s3_bucket = self.s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
        if self.s3_bucket.creation_date:
            print("Successfully connected to bucket {}".format(bucket_name))
        else:
            raise Exception("bucket {} doesnt exist or there are no permissions".format(bucket_name))

    def check_if_object_exist(self, obj: dict) -> bool:
        full_path_in_s3 = "{}/{}/{}".format(obj['vendor'], date.today(), obj['file_name'])
        try:
            self.s3_bucket.Object("{}".format(full_path_in_s3)).get()
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as ex:
            if ex.response['Error']['Code'] == 'NoSuchKey':
                return False
        return True
```

I'm using the check_if_object_exist very often so I decided to open one connection to s3 and work with that connection.
When I run my unittests on this class and it finishes (successfully) I'm seeing the following warning :

```
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py:628: ResourceWarning: unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket fd=944, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('ip', 54602), raddr=('ip', 443)>
```

Should I create a boto3.Session each time I call the func ?

NOTE : I noticed in my tests, that for every call for the check_if_object_exist func I'm getting this msg.

Comment: I would ignore it. Boto3 sessions aren't close-able, so there isn't much you can do about that.

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha first time I'm seeing those warning. I never happened before when I used the boto3 library.

Comment: Take a look at this (btw one of the first links if you google the error): https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/454